# Why even link a CSS file?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering why even bother linking an external CSS file to your html or php file or whatever. Why not just include it in your style tags in the html file  itself?

Comment: creating separates css files helps you reuse them across html files

Comment: Furthermore, the browser won't have to re-download all the CSS with every single page load, because it will already be in the browser cache as its own file.

Comment: If you are just starting out I can understand the confusion, especially if you are using PHP or HTML include files to build your site. As mentioned in other answers, the main drawback with doing it this way is that it gets loaded on every request, whereas an external file is loaded once and then cached. Most sites will have a master CSS include and put any page specific styles directly in the head, or create a separate page specific include.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With one "external" CSS file you can style an entire website instead of repeating it for every page.

If you want one page to have a unique style different from the others you can keep the css "internal" to that page.

You can also keep css narrowed down to a single element if you wish by using an "inline" style not effecting the rest of the page or other pages.

You can also use combinations. Whatever works best for your project.

Answer (score 2):

An external style sheet has many advantages. Keeping the styles separate from your HTML content:

- Helps avoid duplication
- Makes maintenance easier
- Allows you to make a site-wide change in one place

Answer (score 0):

Decoupling your HTML and CSS is a style guideline known as the separation of concerns. It's good practice to do so to promote clarity, robustness, adaptability, maintainability, or re-usability.

Also, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/271294/why-is-it-or-was-it-important-to-separate-css-from-html